# Is there way in SharePoint Online to only allow Person who created news post to be able to edit it and prevent others from being able to edit it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I have a requirement where I want users to be able to create new articles but only the person who created new articles should be able to edit the news they created.

Multiple users can create new articles but the users can only edit their own news articles.

Is there anyway we can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct SharePoint out of the box way like list's "Item-level Permissions" to achieve this.

So, you have to achieve this by breaking permissions inheritance on individual site pages & then only grant necessary permissions.

Now, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Manual:

   Any user who creates a new article/news has to manually break the permissions on corresponding page >> keep **Full Control** permissions to himself/herself & then grant **Read** permissions to all other users/groups on site.

**Reference**: [How to prevent team site members from editing SharePoint pages](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/) >> Check OPTION 2: PREVENT EDITING OF A SPECIFIC PAGE - Classical or modern pages

2. Automation:

   - You can run a power automate flow on new page/file creation in site page
   - Identify if it is a news page based on page properties
   - Break permissions inheritance if it is a news page
   - Grant Full control permission to user in "Created By" field & Read permissions to other users/groups as required.